# Как вызвать методы компонента VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Создаю компонент диалога.

Компонент vue, как обычно, состоит из `<template> <script> <style>`.

От компонента требуется простой апи `executeDialog(anyButtonClickedCallback)`.

Я могу вызвать любой метод из секции methods, но не понятно на каком экземпляре он будет вызван, да и скорее всего так делать неправильно.

Я прочитал про общение с компонентами, уяснил одно - если хотим передать информацию компоненту - делаем это через props, если хотим обратную связь от компонента, то делаем это через события, на которые мы подписываемся в parent-компоненте. Это мне подходит, но не в полной мере.

Собственно сейчас секция `<script>` у компонента выглядит примерно так:

```
export default {
    components: {...},
    data() {
        return {
            position: {...}
        }
    },
    props: {
        width: {type: String, required: true},
        header: {type: String, required: true},
        buttons: {...}
    },
    methods: {
        drag(event){...},
        dlialogButtonClick(buttonKey){
            this.$emit("dialog-button-click", buttonKey);
        }
    },
    computed: {...}
}
```

В таком случае, например, видимостью диалога приходится управлять вручную. Это переключение видимости, обработка событий требует выделения этой логики в отдельные функции родителя. Хотелось бы это всё инкапсулировать в самом компоненте.

Как такие проблемы принято решать во vue?
Какие идеи, подходы?

Comment: За полноценный ответ не сойдет, но вот вариант через промисы и события. Первое что пришло в голову, а потом разонравилось. Нужно сделать глобальный сервис, который бы открывал модальное окно сам и отдавал бы этот самый промис тебе. Чтобы замутить сервиса времени не хватило. Если никто не ответит, то попробую конечно что-нибудь набросать, а пока только [ссылка в песочницу](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-nmbim).

Comment: Прикольно, но переменная open в App.vue не несёт в себе вообще никакого смысла, она может быть true/false независимо от того, открыт сейчас диалог или нет. У неё какое-то странное поведение, и её значение не отражает реальной ситуации на странице. Она как-бы переменная, но ведёт себя как функция. А ModalWindow не имеет право её менять. Получается то, о чём я говорил, приходится терпеть эту логику в App.vue.

Comment: Переменная служит сигналом чтобы открыть окно.  Можно воспользоваться ссылкой на компонент и дёрнуть внутренний метод окна, который бы вернул точно также промис. Так пропадет необходимость в event и watch, но этот вариант не гибкий. Лучше сервис.

Comment: Ведь цель была в том чтобы модальное окно само управляла своим состоянием. Поэтому внешний v-if нам не подходит.

Comment: Самостоятельно набросать решение времени не хватило, но перед этим смотрел иные решение. Направлять на другие ресурсы конечно не дело, но прошло 5 дней и никто не ответил. Вот [пример](https://medium.com/@koonradstraszewski/how-to-create-a-modal-service-in-vue-js-43b6b2e7057) с промисома и сервисом.